# equaling indexPathForRow with UItextField

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, ios4

i am trying to implement something that user can insert an number then program show me the row number but i little bit confusing , i would be grateful if you help me , here is my code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < myTextField.text; i++) {
[myScrollTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0 ] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

the compiler shows me a Warning and app crashes what can i do to equal my UtextField with indexPathForRow ?

**warning alert: comparison between pointer and integer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the textfield value to an int. That's what the compiler is warning you about.

```
for(int i = 0; i < [myTextField.text intValue]; i++) { ...
```

Not sure why you're using a loop if you only want to scroll to the row. Use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` (Reference Doc)[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a)

Comment: thanks works great , i have 494 rows , and have big problem with UISearchBar , your code works great but but if i insert big number like 389 , doesn't scroll !